# How to Get the sprites while TouchesMoved over that sprites

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am having 20 sprites in my scene.
When i move one sprite i want to get what are the sprites were getting touched.When my moving sprite touched.

Can any one help me with code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
 for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
 {
   CCSprite *currentSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i+tagOffset];

   if(CGRectIntersectsRect([movingSprite boundingBox],[currentSprite boundingBox]))   
   {
      // current sprite touched
      Break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: what should be tagOffset? where i want to deleclare and what would be initialized?

Comment: I am not getting  the result for this question.